# Conditional tag in wordpress to retrieve current taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

I looking for some conditional tag to get me the taxonomy in the current page.for example when i want to check the current page if it have the same post type that i want it, i use :

```
if('my_post_type' == get_post_type()) {
  // Do Somthing
}
```

is any body can point me to the some conditional like what i say above ?

Comment: So you want the taxonomy an object (like a page or post) has terms for? Or the taxonomy of the current term archive?

Comment: i have some custom taxonomies and i assigned some terms to theme, and also i have some custom post types.
so i try to know when a user view some page i check is one of that taxonomies assigned to it or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attempt to grab the first taxonomy an object has terms for like so:

```
/**
 * Get primary taxonomy that a post belongs to.
 */
function so_8488829_get_primary_taxonomy( $post = null )
{
    $primary = '';

    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
        return $primary;


    foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type ) as $taxonomy ) {
        if ( get_object_term_cache( $post->ID, $taxonomy ) ) {
            $primary = $taxonomy;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $primary;
}
```

So in use, you can try;

```
if ( so_8488829_get_primary_taxonomy() == 'my_taxonomy' ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i trying to find the original function in wordpress for more performance.

Comment: There is no native function to get the *taxonomy* a post has terms for (at least not to my knowledge). You can try `is_object_in_taxonomy( $post_type, $taxonomy )`, but that only checks to see if a taxonomy was *registered* for that post type.

Comment: thanks DeadMedic i use the 
`<?php if(is_object_in_taxonomy( get_post_type(),'cars')) _e('Something') ?>`.
it works fine.